# Can't take screenshot with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, screenshot

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.

All goes well but I can't take screen-shot with the shortcut <kbd>print</kbd> key. In the shortcuts settings the key is recognized.

Previously installed Ubuntu 13.04 and the shortcut worked.

Comment: in the dash, if you search "Screenshot", does Screenshot appear?

Comment: If you use Shutter and it is running the `Print Screen` key may not work.

Comment: I guess you have got an HP, because I have the same problem. As far as I know, it is a 14.04 bug ( link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1282649)

Comment: Alt-Printscreen worked on my HP laptop.

Comment: Here's a link to the bug with print screen button and HP: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1313754

Answer (score 4):

Dependent on the desktop you use (I don't know, if you use Unity-Desktop or Gnome-Shell or even KDE),there is a different way, how to find the app "screenshot". It is installed by default.

- In Gnome-Shell: go to your menu and there go to accessories.
  There you will find "screenshot".
- In Unity:       go to the unity-lens and look for all your installed apps.
  There you should find "Screenshot".
- In Cinnamon:    go to your menu and there to "accessories" and there to "screenshot"
- In KDE:         to to your KDE-menu and there to "accessories" and there look for
  "screenshot".

This app is really easy to handle and lets you save your screenshot in your selected folder. So no problem of taking screenshots in Ubuntu or even LinuxMint.

Comment: but the problem I think is not able to take sceen-shot with **print** key pressed, though ScreenShot application is already installed. Because I am also facing this problem in my HP g6 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 freshly installed.

Comment: the screenshot app is working fr me, the problem is using the PrtSc key. I'm using cinamon right now but the key works under the gnome desktop environment.

Answer (score 3):

As I understood from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1282649) it is problem with HP laptops, and **prt sc** button will work normally when you connect a usb keyboard.

As temporary solution till the bug is fixed we can change shortcut for screenshot to some unassigned key combinations.

Goto **System Settings > Keyboard** change Print to F12 etc.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Same problem on HP Pavilion dm1. My solution is to press <kbd>Fn + Delete</kbd>

Not much of an issue for me since the delete key is just beside the prt sc key. Beats having to go through lines of code. I guess its a case of wrong keyboard mapping. Hope this helps.

Comment: I Have the same problem. I tend to prefer this solution, because when once the bug will be fixed, the original shortcut should work as it is supposed to. So no shortcut changing for me!

Comment: osum..Fn+delete worked for me..and if you want to take screenshot of specific area use Fn+shift+delete. Then it will show you selector cursor

Answer (score 1):

On my new Toshiba satellite, the F keys customization overrides the standard mapping.

Press the FN key and hold before the usual regular variations - I tried all three and works fine for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I have 14.04 with GNOME 3 and LXDE desktop (I don't use Unity)

For GNOME 3 the screenshot goes to my `home/<username>/Pictures` folder.

For LXDE the screenshot goes to my `home/<username>` folder.

In LXDE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> requires you to highlight the screen area using the mouse.

In older Ubuntu versions I got a popup window asking me whether I wanted to save the file or just copy the image to the clipboard. Now it apparently just saves the file.

LDXE: In my `/home/<username>/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` file it shows that I am running `scrot` when I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and `scrot -s` when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

Sorry, I can't check the location in Unity, but I would recommend you doing a file search and press the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button to see where the PNG files are popping up.

LDXE is just an alternative desktop to replace Unity or GNOME. It is still Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also I am using a desktop computer with a USB keyboard.