# Why are some of my screen-recording/capturing/sharing applications (or app features) not working in Ubuntu 17.10 (and later releases)?

Tags: 17.10, screenshot, screencast, desktop-sharing

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 I noticed some of my screencasting applications are not working, for example screencasting tools like *SimpleScreenRecorder* and *vokoscreen*. ([link](https://askubuntu.com/q/966633/480481))

Also I noticed features like screenshot from GIMP is not working properly, producing blank screenshots ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966596/gimp-produces-black-screenshot-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10?noredirect=1)). Shutter too is producing glitchy screenshots ([link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1010406/480481)).

Screen-sharing option on Skype is also not working ([link](https://askubuntu.com/q/979799/480481)).

The issue occurs sometimes on later Ubuntu releases too.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: More technical answers and/or possible workarounds are most welcome. Already seeing questions like this, I'm guessing there will be more in next few days.

Comment: related for 14.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/459157/cant-take-screenshot-with-14-04

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.10 by default lets users log in to a GNOME environment on a Wayland session. You may check whether you're logged into a Wayland session instead of an Xorg (X11) session by running the following command in Terminal:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Applications which are not compatible with Wayland yet run under a XWayland compatibility layer. But advanced applications, which depend on and/or control X11 server "too much" (screen-capturing/recording etc.), might fail to run in a Wayland session.

As a workaround you may [switch back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: What does one loose by running an Xorg session and not a Wayland session?

Comment: @Masroor [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better) is a very good read. tl;dr: X is a legacy technology with many flaws and holes, but then again Wayland is not that much supported.

Comment: Interesting results :-)

Comment: @pomsky No, the screenshot feature does not work once I switch back to Wayland.

Comment: @Masroor If you have a hidpi display, then Wayland is a much better choice. In general Wayland handles hidpi displays in a much more smooth way, and only Wayland supports the scenario that one of your monitors is hidpi and the other one is not. On Xorg scaled/hidpi is _all in_ or _all out_.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, it's only a work around for some.  I've been running Xorg on Ubuntu 18.04 for quite some time and since a week ago more or less, suddenly the screenshot tool doesn't copy anything into the clipboard any more.  I can't "switch back to Xorg" since I'm already running it.

Comment: @LifeBoy Ask a new question, sounds like a completely separate issue. How are you trying to copy to clipboard anyway?

Comment: @pomsky I'm doing exactly what this question describes.  Press `ctrl shift prtsc` and get the crosshair pointer, select an area and click.  Shutter sound is produced, but nothing ends up in the clipboard.

Comment: @LifeBoy I don't see *where exactly in this question* this method is described. Anyway, how are confirming that *nothing ends up in the clipboard*? Where exactly are you trying to paste it?As I said before, different issue, consider asking a new question. Discussing in comments is *not* to right way to get solutions for your problem. Also tbh I cannot reproduce, screenshots getting copied to clipboard and I can paste in applications like GIMP without an issue.

Comment: Using Wayland fixed OBS screen recording for me on 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Try Green Recorder. It supports Wayland & Xorg and it will work with Ubuntu 17.10. For installation instructions please check this **[link](https://connectwww.com/green-recorder-screen-recorder-for-linux/5569/)**

Open terminal and run all the below commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossproject/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install green-recorder
green-recorder
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: I disagree, workarounds are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to playback a video recorded using 'Kazam' and encoded using H.264, I'd recommend trying out different video playback applications. I noticed that some applications (specifically in my case, VLC) played back the audio fine but produced a black screen for the video. The default totem player seemed to playback the video fine, however.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this workaround in Wayland. (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
sleep 3s; gnome-screenshot -a -f /tmp/scr.png && \
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i /tmp/scr.png
```