# Record screen, microphone and web camera in Ubuntu 17.10 (Wayland Session)

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, 17.10, wayland

I want to record my screen, audio and webcam in Ubuntu 17.10.

I have tried the following software (from this thread [How can I record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen)):

- gtk-recordmydesktop: Missing web camera support
- xvidcap: Missing web camera support
- Kazam: Wont start
- Simple Screen Recorder: Missing web camera support
- VOKOSCREEN: Records only black screen
- Tibesti: Missing web camera support
- VLC: Missing web camera support, could not get it to record at all
- OBS: Will not start
- ScreenStudio: Will not start

Any suggestion for good software to do this?

---

After some digging I found out that if I start Ubuntu 17.10 in X Server instead of Wayland then Vokoscreen works and meets my requirements.

Comment: Someone suggested "Green Recorder": https://askubuntu.com/a/967989/, not sure how helpful will that be in your case.

Answer (score 10):

If you're really inclined to further use Wayland you should give [green-recorder](https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder) a try.

It even is able to record games you play, only caveat is that it only records as WebM format under Wayland. Have to mention that it only records the screen, not a webcam for example.

[image: screenshot]

To install it you need to add a new ppa into your system, so you can follow the steps below to install it from terminal command line.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossproject/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install green-recorder
```

To add to this you might want to install TopIcons plus extension from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) to be able to access green-recorder when it has started recording.

---

The only other chance you have to get the software you mentioned to work again is starting your desktop under Xorg as display-manager.

To do so you have to log out and use the cogwheel beside the sign in button to choose 'Ubuntu on Xorg'.

[image]

---

An other possibility to just create a smaller screen-cast of about 30 seconds would be to just press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> this will leave the recorded bit in your 'Video' directory in your home (`/home/$USER/Video/`). Thus this solution does not seem to work under Xorg and producing files of 0 Byte length.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it supports web camera?

Comment: No, only screen recording, sadly not even cheese is running under wayland

Comment: If someone can recommend a webcam recording solution i gladly will add it into my answer.

Comment: @Videonauth "Not even cheese is running under Wayland." Really ? I am running a fedora 26 workstation with vanilla GNOME 3.24 DE in a Wayland session at the moment and `cheese` works right as expected. Well, there are two possibilities : 1) Something is broken in your installation. 2) In case that every user can confirm what you say, this might be an Ubuntu specific problem. Anyway, +1 for your nice answer ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Oh I would be glad to get confirmation on Ubuntu systems and will be even more glad to edit that out if it is only with my test installation.

Comment: @Tim 16.04 uses still Xorg as display-manager, the change to wayland came with 17.10 and if we can trust OMGUbuntus homepage, they will revert back from Wayland to Xorg for 18.04.