# Screenshot feature of Shutter doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, screenshot, shutter

After the last upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10, the screenshot feature of Shutter doesn't work properly any more.

When I press `Selection`, or `Desktop` to get a screenshot of the entire desktop, the image gets filled with large Shutter icons, like this:

I tried to `purge` Shutter, then reinstalled, but the problem persists. I also tried to update Shutter, but I already have the last version.

It's worth mentioning that there's just an association between upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 and the screenshot feature not working. I'm not sure if the upgrade has caused this, I only know the feature stopped working immediately after the upgrade.

What can I do to fix Shutter's screenshot feature?

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966779/why-are-some-of-my-screen-recording-capturing-applications-or-app-features-not?

Comment: A lot, thanks. [Changed to a Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) and it works. Can you please post an answer so it's more visible? And I can also give you credits for your help. @pomsky

Comment: I beleive the issue is wayland (the default for 17.10), many applications seem to be having trouble with fullscreen capture under wayland. At login try Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: Cool, will do @pomsky!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `gnome-screenshot` if you can not get Shutter to work.

I have used `gnome-screenshot` for some time and it works before and after the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. It does full screen, frames or "select area".

Finally, have you tried uninstalling / re-installing? I know this is a "Windows-esque" solution, but, well, you never know.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround by I fixed this switching to a [Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: I suggest this person's OSS lciense is revoked, chaps. Reinstall? Blasphemy!

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all, using another program does not fix the issue, also the OP said he purged and reinstalled