# Bug in screen capture with Shutter on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, bug-reporting, shutter

Is it normal that on 17.10 Shutter doesn't work properly? When I try to get a screenshot, all I get is this stuff:
[image: Bug in screen capturing]

Is there a way to fix it? Are there working alternatives to Shutter for 17.10?

Comment: No, it's not normal when a feature does not work as intended. Have you checked to see if this bug has been reported?

Comment: This happens to me in OpenSUSE leap 15.0 I solved with this https://askubuntu.com/a/961345/658488

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the default and pre-installed screenshot application without any issue. You can launch it by running `gnome-screenshot -i` (interactive mode) in Terminal or simply by searching for "Screenshot" in "Activities".

If it is not installed by any chance, you can install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

Once you've captured screenshots using this application, you should be able to open them with Shutter and edit.