# Shutter 0.94 in Ubuntu 18.04.1 taking wrong screenshoots

Tags: gnome-shell, shutter

For some reason shutter is taking the screenshots as a mix of its icon instead of real ones. Any similar issue with certain solutions?

This is an example screenshot:

[image: Example issued images]

Comment: Are you by any chance in a Wayland session? What's the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @pomsky, confirmed, it's wayland

Comment: Then it seems identical to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010406/bug-in-screen-capture-with-shutter-on-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Videonauth in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403325/shutter-broke-my-printscreen?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment720989_403325) changing the login to Ubuntu Xorg now this work. Also the question from @pomsky route me to the solution. Now XDG_SESSION_TYPE is x11