# Gnome issues - freezing and screenshots

Tags: gnome, xfce, vlc, gimp

In past week I notice a serious problem on my Ubuntu system, and I don't know **how to find out a reason for it** (I guess that it is caused by some update, but how to find out"?)

Two issues show up:

1. when I play video files in VLC (files are from remote mounted network ftp) then sometimes (once in a day) it it freezes my desktop. I hear that video continues to play, but desktop is frozen. I can't even switch to ctrl + alt + F consoles. Reboot is only option. I noticed that it mostly happens when I have VLC in windowed mode and I hover with my mouse over VLC somewhere around 'progress bar' which shows how far is it in video file.
2. when I try to do a screenshot, either through xfce4-screenshooter or gimp screenshot feature, I get either black image or corrupted image.

I use "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" (bionic), desktop "ubuntu:GNOME", all packages are up-to-date; gimp 2.8.22; xfce4-screenshooter 1.8.2; I have desktop on two displays. Graphics card "Radeon HD 5870".

I don't see anything suspicious in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: I believe you've logged into a Wayland session. Switch back to Xorg, it should fix both the issues. Also try disabling the full screen controls for VLC (preferences -> show settings all -> Interface -> Main Interfaces -> Qt -> Show a controller in full-screen mode).

Comment: I am logging in as usual into session called "Ubuntu" (which I believe is gnome desktop), other options I have are "Ubuntu on Xorg", "Unity", "session xfce" and "session xubuntu".
VLC problem - it happens when I use windowed mode, not fullscreen, I will update it in the post.
So I will test it with "ubuntu on xorg" for few days, I see that it fixes screenshot problem (though I would be interested how to find out what is the problem, in logs or somewhere)

Comment: So far looks good, 5 days without a freeze :-)
So where is the problem in Wayland, and how to report it?

Comment: The issue with screenshots is already discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966779/why-are-some-of-my-screen-recording-capturing-applications-or-app-features-not), and right place to report bugs is launchpad.net.