# Cannot screenshare on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vnc, lts, desktop-sharing

[image]

I don't see any option for sharing the screen as we see in this [link](https://websiteforstudents.com/access-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-desktop-via-vnc-from-windows-machines/). 
Also, the sharing button automatically switches off if I navigate away from this screen. If I try to share the entire screen from the browser(during discussions), a black page is shared. 
vino is already the newest version (3.22.0-3ubuntu1). I've tried many available solutions related to this issue. I don't know what's wrong. Kindly help. The ubuntu version I'm using is 18.04

Comment: Are you by any chance in a Wayland session? What does `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` say?

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for the reply. Its says "wayland"

Comment: That's the problem, you need to switch to Xorg. Does this answer your question? [Why are some of my screen-recording/capturing/sharing applications (or app features) not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966779/why-are-some-of-my-screen-recording-capturing-sharing-applications-or-app-featu)

Comment: @pomsky Thanks a ton. That was indeed the problem. You could have posted it as an answer. Switched from wayland to x11 and it seems to be working.

Comment: In that case please click the 'this answers my question' button. No harm in that, it just helps keeping similar questions linked together for future readers.